# android ListView OnItemClickListener sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onclicklistener

He creado una consulta mediante un ListView desde una base de datos local, no necesito que se muestre toda la informacion del registro, solo los basicos, ya que tambien he creado un OnitemClickListener para que cuando se pulse un dato de los existentes en el ListView me lleve a una nueva activity.
El problema esta en que no se como establecer los datos de la nueva activity
Este es el codigo:

Actualizacion: ya resolvi el problema gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad, el codigo mas abajo es totalmente funcional

Este es el codigo de la consulta mediante el ListView

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.beeo.proyecto_final.constantes.Constante;
import com.example.beeo.proyecto_final.entidades.Cliente;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConsultarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView datos;
ArrayList<String> lista_datos;
ArrayList<Cliente> lista_usuario;
Conexion con;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consultar);

    con = new Conexion(getApplicationContext(), "db_proyecto",null,1);

    datos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_datos);

    consultar_lista_datos();

    ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista_datos);

    datos.setAdapter(adaptador);

    datos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //Cliente es un constructor que tiene la informacion de las entidades de la base de datos asi como los get y set
            Cliente idCliente = lista_usuario.get(position);

            Intent actividad = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetalleActivity.class);

            actividad.putExtra("id",idCliente);

            startActivity(actividad);


        }
    });





}

private void consultar_lista_datos() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
    Cliente usuario = null;

    lista_usuario = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+Constante.tabla_cliente,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        usuario = new Cliente();
        usuario.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        usuario.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
        usuario.setApellido(cursor.getString(2));
        usuario.setCedula(cursor.getString(3));

        lista_usuario.add(usuario);

    }

    obtener_lista();

}

private void obtener_lista() {
    lista_datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i<lista_usuario.size(); i++){
        lista_datos.add(lista_usuario.get(i).getId()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getNombre()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getApellido()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getCedula());
    }
}
```

}

Este es el codigo de la DetalleActivity

```
  Cliente id =(Cliente)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("id");


    nombre.setText(id.getNombre());
```

OJO: tengo dos metodos constructores, uno vacio el cual no recibe parametros al cual le añadi implements Serializable, entonces quedaria asi: public class Cliente implements Serializable y otro que si recibe los parametros normales para la base de datos

Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ejecutar el evento setOnIntemCliclListener te llega una posición con esa posicion puedes buscar el Id del registro:

```
import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.example.beeo.proyecto_final.constantes.Constante;
    import com.example.beeo.proyecto_final.entidades.Cliente;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConsultarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView datos;
    ArrayList<String> lista_datos;
    ArrayList<Cliente> lista_usuario;
    Conexion con;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consultar);

        con = new Conexion(getApplicationContext(), "db_proyecto",null,1);

        datos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_datos);

        consultar_lista_datos();

        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista_datos);

        datos.setAdapter(adaptador);

        datos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int idCliente = lista_usuario.get(position).getId();
                Intent actividad = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetalleActivity.class);

                actividad.putExtra("idCliente",idCliente);

            }
        });





    }

    private void consultar_lista_datos() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = con.getReadableDatabase();
        Cliente usuario = null;

        lista_usuario = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+Constante.tabla_cliente,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            usuario = new Cliente();
            usuario.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            usuario.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            usuario.setApellido(cursor.getString(2));
            usuario.setCedula(cursor.getString(3));

            lista_usuario.add(usuario);

        }

        obtener_lista();

    }

    private void obtener_lista() {
        lista_datos = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i<lista_usuario.size(); i++){
            lista_datos.add(lista_usuario.get(i).getId()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getNombre()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getApellido()+" - "+lista_usuario.get(i).getCedula());
        }
    }
}
```

pasas el ID del registr a tu otra actividad y por medio de ese lo buscar y traes todos los valores y los seteas donde desees

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha funcionado para poder avanzar a la siguiente actividad, pero, no he podido dar con la  forma de que me ponga el nombre en el EditText, he escrito lo siguiente:   Intent entero = getIntent(); y luego esta linea: nombre.setText(entero.getStringExtra("nombre")); y muchas otras formas mas de hacerlo, pero, no entiendo el por que no me funciona T_T